# C# create a hierachical object

Tags: c#, class

I am creating a logging system. It is very basic and a good exercise to learn about creating classes.  However, I'm stuck and have been on this for a week.

The project is a copy and paste project (a backup solution) and for each file it copies, I want to save the following: The Title, Status and MoreDetails (all of type string).

I would like to see the title of the file and the status at root level, but I would like to drill deeper in to see the moreDetails. I hope the 'textual diagram' below will help illustrate my point.

```
-logFile
-0
      Title         Value
      Status        Value
     +MoreDetails
-1
      Title         Value
      Status        Value
     +MoreDetails
-2
      Title         Value
      Status        Value
     +MoreDetails
```

Please note, I don't want to write this to a file/database as I want to have this in memory - I know this may not be a good idea but it's an exercise at present.

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment of OP, it is answered by T I, to use the [Composite Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx)

[image]